# How can I debug this plotting issue?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The columns are:

```
Company

Location

DateTime

Details
```

Outcome: Prelaunch Failure / Partial Failure / Failure / Success

Write a program to do the following:

1. Create a pie plot that shows the distribution of mission outcomes.
2. Create a horizontal bar plot showing the total number of missions for each company, with the most at the top and the fewest at the bottom.
3. Create the same horizontal bar plot, but with the missions grouped into success and failure, with success in green and failure in red.

For 3. I should be getting a plot as below:

[image]

But I am getting as following:

[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, how can I fix it? Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read the data file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

#Length of dataframe
total = len(df)

#Success percentage
success = (len(df[df['Outcome'] == 'Success'])/total) * 100 

#Failure percentage
failure = (len(df[df['Outcome'] == 'Failure'])/total) * 100

#Partial failure percentage
partial_failure = (len(df[df['Outcome'] == 'Partial Failure'])/total) * 100 

#Prelaunch failure percentage
prelaunch_failure = (len(df[df['Outcome'] == 'Prelaunch Failure'])/total) * 100 

dict_1 = {} 

# Iterate through company column
for k in df['Company']: 
    if k in dict_1: 
        dict_1[k] += 1
    else:
        dict_1[k] = 1

sorted_dict = {}

#Sort dictionary
sorted_keys = sorted(dict_1, key=dict_1.get, reverse=True) 

for w in sorted_keys:
    
# Add sorted values in the new dictionary
  sorted_dict[w] = dict_1[w] 

dict_3 = {} 
dict_4 = {} 

#Iterate through unique Companies
for c in df['Company'].unique(): 
    failure = 0 

#Get only the outcome column of each company
    comp_proj = df.loc[df['Company'] == c, 'Outcome'] 
    for h in comp_proj: 
        if h == 'Failure' or h == 'Partial Failure' or h == 'Prelaunch Failure':
            failure = failure + 1
dict_3[c] = failure   
dict_2 = {} 
for l in dict_2.keys(): 
    dict_4[l] = dict_3[l]

# Plot Pie Chart
figure1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,15))
status = [success,failure,partial_failure,prelaunch_failure]
label = ["success","failure","partial","prelaunch"]
ax1.pie(status,labels=label)
ax1.set_ylabel("Outcome")
plt.savefig('plot 1.png')

# Plot the first bar chart
figure2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
ax2.barh(range(len(sorted_dict)), sorted_dict.values(), align='center')
ax2.set_yticks(range(len(sorted_dict)))
ax2.set_yticklabels(sorted_dict.keys())
ax2.set_ylabel("Company")
ax2.invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig('plot 2.png')

# Plot the second bar chart
figure3, ax3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
ax3.barh(range(len(sorted_dict)), sorted_dict.values(), align='center', color='green')
ax3.barh(range(len(dict_4)), dict_4.values(), align='center', color='red')
ax3.set_yticks(range(len(sorted_dict)))
ax3.set_yticklabels(sorted_dict.keys())
ax3.set_ylabel("Company")
ax3.legend(["Success", "Failure"])
ax3.invert_yaxis()  
plt.savefig('plot 3.png')
```

Sample of data:

[image]

Comment: Please share the underlying data (a sample of it). It is otherwise very hard to test what you've done.

Comment: Just shared a portion of the data for your convenience.

Comment: indenting line "dict_3[c] = failure"  should resolve the issue.

Comment: @SAL I don't think so, it didn't change anything. :/

Comment: dict_4, which is what you use to drive the red bars, doesn't contain anything.  You set dict_2 empty, then populate dict_4 using the empty set of keys.  You need to print your intermediate values to make sure they have what you expect.

Comment: I have fixed it, all good!